# Doctrine - Relation is not created in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am working with Symfony and Doctrine.
When the schema is created through the console command `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` it does not create the relations, which I want it to.

Two Classes:

**Candidates** ORM Entity Class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Libraries\Data;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="candidates")
 */
class Candidates
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Votes", mappedBy="nCandidate")
     */
    private $nID;

    /**
     * Get nID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNID()
    {
        return $this->nID;
    }
}
```

**Votes** ORM Entity Class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Libraries\Data;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="votes")
 */
class Votes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Candidates", inversedBy="nID")
     */
    private $nCandidate;

    /**
     * Get nID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNID()
    {
        return $this->nID;
    }

    /**
     * Set nCandidate
     *
     * @param integer $nCandidate
     *
     * @return Votes
     */
    public function setNCandidate($nCandidate)
    {
        $this->nCandidate = $nCandidate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nCandidate
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNCandidate()
    {
        return $this->nCandidate;
    }
}
```

The doctrine config section in **config.yml** looks like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: false
        mappings:
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            AppBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Libraries/Data"
                prefix: AppBundle\Libraries\Data
```

The relations that should be created are not visible in PHPMyadmin or MySQL Workbench.

Comment: is Doctrine meta data cache enabled ?

Comment: @Vamsi I did not specifically enable anything, is this in the config?

Comment: Do you get any error or just nothing created ? what does output command  php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql ?

Comment: @Thomas The console does not display any errors, output: `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

Comment: Why not trying to use auto_mapping = true and delete the "mappings" section of your config ?

Comment: @Thomas When I do this no tables are created

Comment: @Orlando my bad it's logic as symfony is expecting entities to be in Entity folder, anyway i added an answer you could try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID column of each table had the property name `$nID`, but it has to be `$id`.

I also removed the `@ORM\Column(type="integer")` comment above each property with a `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Class", inversedBy="ID")` relation to an `ID` primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have Placed those Entities in non standard directory that Symfony expects, you have configured Doctrine ORM correctly by setting custom mapping..

The issue appears to be because of the lack of primary key in the Votes Entity.

Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

Votes entity with `* @ORM\Id`

> AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Votes

```
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


   /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
```

Edit :
This is the SQL I got ( MySQL ) when I run

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

CREATE TABLE candidates (
    n_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (n_id)
    ) DEFAULT CHAR

SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE votes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
    ,n_candidate INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) DEFAULT CHAR

SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: I added an ID column, but the relation is still not there

Comment: did you clear the cache ?  php app/console cache:clear and  php app/console  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata

Comment: Did not help, relations are not created

Comment: can you run  php app/console  doctrine:mapping:info   and check if all your Entities are showing up ? also I added the SQL to the above answer .

Comment: Its supposed to show the FQCN of the Entity.. if its showing all the Entity names you expect then theres nothing to worry about if custom mappings are used or not..   Did you also check  ``` php app/console doctrine:schema:validate ```

Comment: Also returns that everything is okay

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

Candidate entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Libraries\Data;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="candidates")
 */
class Candidates
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nID;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Votes", mappedBy="candidate")
     */
    private $vote;

    /**
     * Get nID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNID()
    {
        return $this->nID;
    }
}
```

Vote entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Libraries\Data;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="votes")
 */
class Votes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nCandidate;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Candidates", inversedBy="vote")
    */
    private $candidate;
    /**
     * Get nID
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNID()
    {
        return $this->nID;
    }

    /**
     * Set nCandidate
     *
     * @param integer $nCandidate
     *
     * @return Votes
     */
    public function setNCandidate($nCandidate)
    {
        $this->nCandidate = $nCandidate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nCandidate
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getNCandidate()
    {
        return $this->nCandidate;
    }
}
```

Then run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see if doctrine is aware of the relation

Comment: This throws an error: `[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] Column name `id` referenced for relation from AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Votes towards AppBundle\Libraries\Data\Candidates does not exist.` when I run the console command. When I add `@ORM\Column(type="integer")` above the relation it recognizes the change but does not create a relation.